# Recyclerview measure scroll distance to disable keyboard

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, android-scroll

I want to hide keyboard if user starts scrolling in `RecyclerView`.
`dy` is scrolled distance if I understood that correctly, and if it passes certain value, I can hide keyboard.

But I found out if you press and hold the finger on screen and scroll slowly, it will not change `dy` value (its still `1`) that means my method is not working.

Anyone know other alternative how to handle this specific usecase?

Code:

```
list.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
     override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
              if (dy.absoluteValue > KEYBOARD_HIDE_DIST) editText.clearFocus()
     }
})
```

Comment: If you are using a linear layout manager you could add a listener to that and hide the keyboard on any change

Answer (score 0):

Use this function **computeVerticalScrollOffset()** on recyclerView it will give the offset of scroll position

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
           @Override
           public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                   super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                   Log.d("Scrolled","Distance Scrolled : "+ recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset());
           }
       });
```

Not started with kotlin yet, Hence I have added java code. Hope you got the thing. Let me know if it works for you